# How to get python module imapclient working or what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get to know RPi and its GPIO, and I came across this little project - Gmail LED Notifier. So I installed every single package and module that is necessary, saved my script, chmod'd +x and now I'm getting this error (from IMAPClient):

```
File "./mail.py", line 32, in loop
print('%d messages in INBOX' % select_info['EXISTS'])
KeyError: 'EXISTS'
```

Could you help me get this running?
EDIT: My code (this fragment):

```
def loop():
server = IMAPClient(HOSTNAME, use_uid=True, ssl=True)
server.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)

if DEBUG:
    print('Logging in as ' + USERNAME)
    select_info = server.select_folder(MAILBOX)
    print('%d messages in INBOX' % select_info['EXISTS'])

folder_status = server.folder_status(MAILBOX, 'UNSEEN')
newmails = int(folder_status['UNSEEN'])

if DEBUG:
    print "You have", newmails, "new emails!"

if newmails > NEWMAIL_OFFSET:
    GPIO.output(GREEN_LED, True)
    GPIO.output(RED_LED, False)
else:
    GPIO.output(GREEN_LED, False)
    GPIO.output(RED_LED, True)

time.sleep(MAIL_CHECK_FREQ)
```

Comment: How we can help if we don't see relevant code?

Comment: The short answer is that your dictionary `select_info` (if it is indeed a dictionary) doesn't have the key 'EXISTS'. Keep in mind keys are case sensitive.

Comment: Are you running the script as root? Otherwise python can't utilize GPIO

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the [documentation](https://imapclient.readthedocs.org/en/stable/#imapclient.IMAPClient.select_folder)

> `select_folder(folder, readonly=False)`
>   Set the current folder on the server.
>
> Future calls to methods such as search and fetch will act on the selected folder.
>
> Returns a dictionary containing the SELECT response. At least the **b'EXISTS'**, **b'FLAGS'** and **b'RECENT'** keys are guaranteed to exist. An
>   example:
>
> ```
> {b'EXISTS': 3,
>  b'FLAGS': (b'\Answered', b'\Flagged', b'\Deleted', ... ),
>  b'RECENT': 0,
>  b'PERMANENTFLAGS': (b'\Answered', b'\Flagged', b'\Deleted', ... ),
>  b'READ-WRITE': True,
>  b'UIDNEXT': 11,
>  b'UIDVALIDITY': 1239278212}
> ```

So, the correct way to address the keys in `select_info` is `select_info[b'EXISTS']`

Comment: @RafalCognomen .. if this answer was helpful to you, consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.